# Nullpointer Error in groovy script while trying to add xpath assertion

Tags: java, xpath, groovy, nullpointerexception, soapui

I am getting an error as

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAssertionByName() on null object error at line: 5

however I am able to add xpath assertion in the test case.
As, I am new to groovy so want to know :-

1. What is the reason that I am getting this error.
2. How can I implement a code for **select from current** option in xpath assertion so that i can add xpath instead of printing some junk value(i have printed "hello" as of now).

```groovy
log.info("Testing Start")
def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project
TSName = "ManagePostpayInsurance_1_0"
StepName = "getInsuranceDetails_FC_004"
project.getTestSuiteList().each {
    if(it.name == TSName) {
        TS = it.name
        it.getTestCaseList().each {
            TC =it.name
            def asserting = project.getTestSuiteByName(TS).getTestCaseByName(TC).getTestStepByName(StepName).getAssertionByName("XPath Match")
            log.info(asserting)
            if (asserting instanceof com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.XPathContainsAssertion){
                project.getTestSuiteByName(TS).getTestCaseByName(TC).getTestStepByName(StepName).removeAssertion(asserting)
            }
            def assertion = project.getTestSuiteByName(TS).getTestCaseByName(TC)getTestStepByName(StepName).addAssertion("XPath Match")
            assertion.path = "declare namespace cor='http://soa.o2.co.uk/coredata_1';\ndeclare namespace man='http://soa.o2.co.uk/managepostpayinsurancedata_1';\ndeclare namespace soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';\n//man:getInsuranceDetails_1Response"
            assertion.expectedContent = "hello"            
        }
    }
}
log.info("Testing Over")
```

**I have attached the error log below.**

```
Mon Nov 27 17:04:12 IST 2017:ERROR:java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAssertionByName() on null object
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAssertionByName() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:32)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.Assertable$getAssertionByName.call(Unknown Source)
    at Script10$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(Script10.groovy:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1297)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$148.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at Script10$_run_closure1.doCall(Script10.groovy:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1297)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$148.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at Script10.run(Script10.groovy:5)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:90)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm badly stuck with the above issue, quick help is really appreciated!!!!
 Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

- Since you are going thru hierarchically, do not require to refer full chain of methods starting from `project`.
- Instead, you could directly access the step objects once you browse to step level. This way, NPE can be avoided.

Here is the fixed script, see the inline relevant comment.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.XPathContainsAssertion
log.info("Testing Start")
def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project
def suiteName = "ManagePostpayInsurance_1_0"
def stepName = "getInsuranceDetails_FC_004"
project.testSuiteList.each { suite ->
    if(suiteName == suite.name) {
        suite.testCaseList.each { kase ->
            kase.testStepList.each { step ->
                if (stepName == step.name) {
                    //Note the change here, directly getting the object from step object
                    def asserting = step.getAssertionByName("XPath Match")
                    log.info(asserting)
                    if (asserting instanceof XPathContainsAssertion){
                        step.removeAssertion(asserting)
                    }
                    def assertion = step.addAssertion("XPath Match")
                    assertion.path = "declare namespace cor='http://soa.o2.co.uk/coredata_1';\ndeclare namespace man='http://soa.o2.co.uk/managepostpayinsurancedata_1';\ndeclare namespace soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';\n//man:getInsuranceDetails_1Response"
                    assertion.expectedContent = "hello"            
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
log.info 'Testing Over'
```